# Modifying resourceEditable with method setProp is not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to modify the value of the property resourceEditable of a given event inside the callback eventDidMount. To do this I am using the method setProp like this :

```
arg.event.setProp('resourceEditable', eventEditable);
```

arg is the argument of the callback eventDidMount.

eventEditable is a variable that takes the value true or false.

When I am doing so, I am getting a warning

> "Could not set prop 'resourceEditable'. Use setExtendedProp instead.".

So I tried to use setExtendedProp but obviously it is not working like I want... The property resourceEditable remains at its previous value and the method is adding an extended property resourceEditable.

Does anyone know how I can solve this ?

I am working with FullCalendar Scheduler v5.11.0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be known. I found a solution from N-Gol on this page :

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5166

Next problem now, using several call of setProp doesn't work properly, only the last call seems to work. Really weird behaviour

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable, and/or provide a code example which is relevant to the specific scenario in the question. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Also, regarding the last sentence of your answer...if you have a new problem, ask a new question - it will not get any attention sat here at the end of an answer. :-)